# Faces messages have been enqueued but may not have been displayed

Tags: jsf

I try to prepare a html page in JSF. I would like to get products by categories and I got the INFO message below.

**INFO MESSAGE**

15:54:32,650 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-1) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=j_idt2:foo[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value '1' for 'null Converter'.), detail=(Conversion Error setting value '1' for 'null Converter'.)]

**INFO MESSAGE ENDED**

Here is a part of my HTML page. I know I should asscoiate may h:selectone Menu with h:messages but don't know how to do.

```
<h1 align="center">
<h:selectOneMenu  align="center" value="#{productsByCategories.selectedCategory}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Category Name"  itemValue = "#{productsByCategories.selectedCategory.categoryName}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{listCategoriesBean.categories}" var="category"
        itemLabel="#{category.id}" itemValue="#{category.id}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
<h:outputText value="&#160;" />
<f:param name="categoryId" value="#{category.id}" />
<h:commandButton action="#{productsByCategories.init()}" value="List Products of Category" />

</h1>
```

Comment: I think may problem is different. I got an ınfo message, saying that, "facesmessages are enqueed but not displayed" so my problem is related to "display" message, I think. Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is indeed two-fold. The abovelinked first duplicate answers the issue wrt the warning message about an enqueued but undisplayed message, and the second duplicate answers your *actual* problem which the actual enqueued message tried to inform you about.